# C# смена ключа в приложении

Tags: c#, textbox, key

У меня есть строка, в которой прописан ключ.

```
string key = "123s4d534s232sg342s3d432";
```

Хочу добавить на форму поле textBox, в котором при желании можно было бы ввести новый ключ.

Можно ли как-то осуществить смену ключа из приложения, когда информация о нем хранится только в exe-файле приложения?

Comment: Вы не думали после завершения ввода сделать `key = textBox.Text`?

Comment: В чём вообще проблема? У вас же строка - не константа. Только, естественно, значение будет сброшено после завершения программы. Если вам нужно его сохранить, используйте настройки приложения, которые будут сохранятся в файле конфигурации где-то в AppData текущего пользователя. Если же это какой-то важный ключ, то его надо зашифровать и положить в файл, а для ввода использовать `PasswordBox`.

Comment: @D.Stark, сейчас у меня ключ хранится в файле. Хочется как бы "вшить" в приложение ключ, с возможностью дальнейшего изменения. Не хочется привязываться к файлу, к расположению файла.

Comment: Зачем привязываться к расположению файла? Храните его в одной папке с приложением. Вы думаете, обязательно прописывать всегда полный путь? Обращайтесь к файлу просто по имени, и он будет лежать в одной директории с вашим приложением.

Comment: Нельзя строчку в .exe вшить и потом её менять прямо там. Да и при открытии в обычном блокноте .exe файла, она тогда была бы видна.

Answer (score 2):

Сам по себе exe-файл представляет собой готовый, скомпилированный исполняемый файл. Менять его содержимое без повторной компиляции не представляется возможным, насколько мне известно.
В данной ситуации я бы посоветовал использовать стандартный файл параметров приложения `Settings.Settings`. Для этого:
1) Открываем `Settings.Settings` в Visual Studio, добавляем новую строку с параметрами: имя - `key`, тип - `string`, область - `пользователь`.
2) Кидаем на форму `textbox` и `button`.
3) `textbox` маскируем под ввод ключа (по-желанию), в методе `button_Click` пишем следующее:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.key = textbox.text;  
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Отныне в этом свойстве можно всегда достать ваш `key`.

Comment: Прежде всего Portable Executable (.exe) остаётся файлом и ничто не мешает его изменить. Более того, он имеет [чёткую структуру](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#.D0.A2.D0.B5.D1.85.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8), а в случае .NET-приложения имеет [удобные инструменты](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) для подобных модификаций.

Comment: @LunarWhisper: Изменение бегущего файла — признак плохого дизайна. Изменяемые части являются _параметрами_, и должны лежать в Settings. Кроме того, снимать блокировку с файла и пытаться заменить строку — грубый хак: компилятор имеет право, например, на предвычисление свойств строковых констант в пуле (например, он может вычислить её хэшкод во время компиляции). То, что он в текущей версии текущей реализации от Microsoft так не делает — случайность.

Comment: @VladD на что я и указал в своём ответе. Но если автор хочет выстрелить себе в ногу, то кто мы такие, чтобы его останавливать? А компилятор этого делать права не имеет, как раз по той причине, что это ответственность JIT-оптимизатора.

Comment: @LunarWhisper: Ну, разве что так. Насчёт JIT, ну это ж подробность текущей имплементации, вон под телефоны всё AOT собираются ввести. // А неужели ж компилятор не имеет права предпросчитать string pool? (Я не в курсе, как он устроен, но логично — по крайней мере, не запрещено спекой — было бы HashSet или Dictionary.)

Comment: @LunarWhisper автор (топикастер) не хочет выстрелить себе в ногу. Он хочет сделать в приложении какую-то настройку со значением по умолчанию. Выстрелить в ногу советуете ему вы :) Я уверен, что большинство приложений, в которых есть тестовые настройки, не хранят их редактированием собственного exe-файла.

Comment: @PashaPash `когда информация о нем хранится только в exe-файле приложения`, допускаю, что автор ошибся и сам не знает - чего хочет. Но вопрос поставлен именно так. :)

Comment: @LunarWhisper: благодарю за дополнительную информацию по Mono Project, учту на будущее =)

Answer (score 1):

Да, [можно](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/HOWTO). Если же ключ твоего приложения уникален **и всегда имеет постоянную длину**, тебе для этого не потребуется ничего: просто открой файл, найди свою строку и замени новой.
Если ты хочешь изменить сам себя, то прежде всего тебе понадобится снять блокировку на запись. Ты можешь либо воспользоваться функциями `WinAPI`: попытаться снять существующую блокировку с файла, разрешив его модификацию; или, при запуске приложения, прочитать его данные в память после чего создать новый процесс из буфера в памяти. Придётся немножко почитать и погуглить.
Если же идти по пути наименьшего сопротивления, то достаточно при запуске сделать копию приложения во временном файле, запустить её ещё раз (передав в качестве параметров запуска путь к оригинальному файлу), после чего модифицировать его сколько душе угодно.

Только учти, что это production-ready решение. Во-первых, непонятно - какое поведение ты ожидаешь, если файл будет запущен несколько раз. Во-вторых, у тебя может просто не быть прав на запись - сетевые шары или просто ограничение в правах. Особенно с учётом того, что нормальные приложения так себя не ведут и больше всего ты будешь со стороны похож на вирус.

Comment: Хотя вообщем то смысл это делать?) Строчка будет, кстати, видна 
в обычном Блокноте. Если только шифровать - ну тогда забываем о фиксированной длине. Я думаю это уже слишком, так что нужно сохранять в файл и шифровать, раз строчка такая прямо важная.

Answer (score 1):

Значит, предлагаю ерундой не заниматься.
Сохраняйте ключ в файл и шифруйте:

```
var rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
// Save this values or not use Rijndael and set values manually:
byte[] key = rijndael.Key;
byte[] iv = rijndael.IV;

// Save key.
string keyString = "KEY STRING";
File.WriteAllBytes("My Important file.dat", AesEncrypt(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(keyString), key, iv));

// Read key.
string readed = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(AesDecrypt(File.ReadAllBytes("My Important file.dat"), key, iv));

 MessageBox.Show(readed);
```

Методы шифрования (вообще, если будете часто шифровать/расшифровывать данные, для оптимизации проводите инициализацию переменных `aesAlgEncryptor`, `aesAlgDecryptor`, `encryptor` и `decryptor` один раз (т.е. можно, например, вынести их из области функции в класс, и задать как `null`, а инициализировать только 1 раз - когда они, как раз, `nullable`)):

```
byte[] AesEncrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv) {

    var aesAlgEncrypt = Aes.Create();
    aesAlgEncrypt.Key = key;
    aesAlgEncrypt.IV = iv;

    var encryptor = aesAlgEncrypt.CreateEncryptor(aesAlgEncrypt.Key, aesAlgEncrypt.IV);

    using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
            csEncrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
            csEncrypt.Close();

            return msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

byte[] AesDecrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv) {

    var aesAlgDecrypt = Aes.Create();
    aesAlgDecrypt.Key = key;
    aesAlgDecrypt.IV = iv;

    var decryptor = aesAlgDecrypt.CreateDecryptor(aesAlgDecrypt.Key, aesAlgDecrypt.IV);

    using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(new MemoryStream(data), decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
       using (var smDecrypt = new MemoryStream()) {
            csDecrypt.Flush();
            csDecrypt.CopyTo(smDecrypt);
            csDecrypt.Close();

            return smDecrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Так же, как предложено в ответе выше, можете использовать настройки (на деле (уже писал, кстати) эти настройки будут сохранены в формате XML в файл где-то в `AppData` текущего пользователя):

[image: Add value to app setting]

(установите `Scope` как `Application`, если всё таки не будете менять значение)

```
Properties.Settings.Default.key = "New value";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
MessageBox.Show(Properties.Settings.Default.key);
```